# How do I replace one object by another in an array of objets with VueJS?

Tags: arrays, object, vue.js

I'm building a website with VueJS and AdonisJS, and I'm setting up a possibility to publish or unpublish an article just by setting the `draft` attribute to `true` or `false`.

This attribute edition is possible from the index, where all the articles can be seen. I made a table where there's an action button that would toggle the attribute, which would send an HTTP POST request to Adonis with the ID.

My concern is for what comes after: I don't believe that replacing the whole array is the good option, but what should I do instead? I tried the following:

```
handlePublish (id) {
  this.$axios.post('/post/publish', {id: id}, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer [some token]`
    }})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      let toDelete = ''
      this.posts.map((post, index) => {
        if (post.id === id) {
          toDelete = index
        }
      })

    this.posts.splice(toDelete, 1)
    this.posts.push(response.data)
 })
 .catch(e => console.log(e.response))
}
```

But somehow nothing gets update, excepted in the database.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you slicing and pushing the entire post when you can simply update your existing post that is already in the array? I mean you are not changing the data structure, you are simply updating an Object property. On `success` you simply need to find the post which you have gotten from your response in your posts array and update its `draft` property.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know it was possible, I thought that somehow I'd corrupt something, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `map` to iterate over array. Instead you can use `map` to get updated array by returning the new element in place of old,

```
.then(response => {
    this.posts = this.posts.map((post, index) => {
        if (post.id === id) {
          return response.data
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm (and it showed me some mistakes I made, so double thanks!)